# What is the center of $\mathbb{C}S_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

How do I found the center of symmetric group algebra $\mathbb{C}S_3$? and in general $\mathbb{C}S_n$?

---

I did an example on a smaller group algebra: $\mathbb{C}S_2=\{a (1)+b(12) \mid a,b\in \mathbb{C}\}$

So the center of $\mathbb{C}S_2=C(\mathbb{C}S_2)=\{x \in \mathbb{C}S_2 \mid \forall g\in \mathbb{C}S_2 ~~ xg=gx\}$

Now fix $x=a(1)+b(12)$ and let $g=a'(1)+b'(12)$

$$xg=[a(1)+b(12)][a'(1)+b'(12)]=(aa'+bb')(1)+(ab'+ba')(12)=gx$$

Hence $C(\mathbb{C}S_2)=\mathbb{C}S_2$

---

Can I apply the same method to find the center of $\mathbb{C}S_3$? Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that given a vector $v\in \mathbb{C}G$, we have that centerality is equivalent to commutation with respect to the basis vectors $1g$ for $g\in G$. Writing $v=\sum_g v_gg$, take $v=hvh^{-1}=\sum_i v_g hgh^{-1}$ so that commutation is equivalent to $v_g=v_{hgh^{-1}}$, or that the coefficents are constant on the conjugacy class of $g$. Thus the center is $\bigoplus_{Z}\mathbb{C}i_{Z}$, where $Z$ goes over all conjugacy classes, and $i_V$ is the indicator function.

Now in the case of $G=S_n$, conjugacy classes corrospond to partition of $n$, so namely in the case of $S_3$, there are three cycle types, $3, 1|2, id$, so that every central element in the the three dimensional vector subspace of $a1+\sum_{i,j} b(ij)+\sum_{i,j,k}c(ijk)$.

Comment: This is a bit off topic, but since we can write $\mathbb{C}G=\bigoplus_i End(V_i)$ where $V_i$ are the irreduicible representations of $G$, which all add exactly one dimension of central elements, coming from the identity endomorphism (since the endomorphism ring is central simple), so that we have found that irreduicible representations are in bijection with conjugacy classes, atleast in number!

Answer (score 0):

There is a ring isomorphism
$$
C(\mathbb{C}S_3)\simeq \mathbb{Z}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \cr 1\cr 1 \end{pmatrix}\oplus 
\mathbb{Z}\begin{pmatrix} 3 \cr -3\cr 0 \end{pmatrix}\oplus \mathbb{Z}\begin{pmatrix} 2 \cr 2\cr -1 \end{pmatrix},
$$
see Example $2.1.4$ [here](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/Brakenhoff.pdf), about the method how to find the center.